# How can I get form input metadata using request.form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have a series of HTML form inputs to the effect of

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Top bugs" name="top_bugs" id="input_1">
```

I retrieve this data and load directly into a dict using

```
dict(request.form)
```

Doing so gives me the key/value as `{top_bugs : value}`. However I would like to some how retrieve the `id`. I do not expect the id to load into the dict, but would like to retrieve it in some way, ideally into a different dict.

Is there a way I can retrieve more than simply name and value from a form input using request.form (or via a different method)?

Comment: You can't. The `id` is not part of the form model, it is part of the HTML only. Why do you need it?

Comment: Dang. Ok thanks. I am hoping to come up with a workaround to my other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666605/how-can-i-reorder-if-statements-based-on-randomized-form-inputs

Comment: Why not just store the order in a hidden field then? Or rename the fields to indicate their order.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what that would look like. Could you post an example?

Comment: Nor am I sure I understand what you are trying to do. If you are randomising the order of a form in JavaScript, you'll have the option to list the field names in the order they appear in the form, and add that information to the form in a `<input type="hidden" />` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the name and value pairs of each element in your form will be passed to your script.

The way I usually achieve this is to pack (serialise) it into the name before sending and then disassemble it at the other end, so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Top bugs" name="top_bugs~input_1" id="input_1">
```

And then:

```
tdict=dict(request.form)
fdict={}
idict={}
for item in tdict.keys():
    (name,id)=item.split("~",1)
    fdict[name]=tdict[item]
    idict[name]=id
```

This should give you the dictionary fdict (which is name=>value) and idict (which is name=>id).

This is a bit hackey, i realise; you may also want to use javascript to append the id to the name when the form is submitted rather than at form creation time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the workaround I was looking for.

Comment: I forgot to mention: This is Python 3 -- I think the `for item in dict` syntax is different for python 2.7

Comment: @SteJ: no, `for item in tdict` works the same way in Python 2 and Python 3. There is never a need to call `dict.keys()` when iterating over a dictionary.

Comment: You do not get a list if you do for item in dict without using dict.keys() in Python3, you get a "dictionary keys" object instead - this doesn't always cause a problem, but it has caused me headaches in the past so I always now use dict.keys() when I want a list of dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to define a hidden element:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Top bugs" name="top_bugs" id="input_1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="top_bugs_id" value="input_1"/>
```

Then you can extract the id value finding the element which has the name + '_id' pattern as name.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer you can't. browsers only send the name and value of fields no matter the method.